# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\cosh(x)+\cosh(y)} \, dy \, dx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hyperbolic-functions

My friend gave me this problem, and I'm not too sure where to start. I know single integrals relatively well, but I'm pretty new to double integrals. If someone could show a step-by-step solution, that would be great.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac 1 {\cosh(x)+\cosh(y)} \, dy \, dx$$

I've tried hyperbolic tangent half-angle substitution and normal substitution, but I have no idea if that applies to double integrals as well.

Comment: The denominator is $2\cosh\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cosh\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$. Now change variables appropriately to get a product of two single integrals.

Comment: Note my edit. A bit of space before $dy$ or $dx$ is standard. And similarly $\Delta y$ or $\Delta x,$ or $\partial x$ in $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial y\,\partial x}. \qquad$

Comment: To concur with @MichaelHardy, really a `\,` space should surround on either side any “item” that consists of more than one character.

Comment: Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\cosh x}=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\,dx}{e^{x}+e^{-x}}=4\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\pi\tag{A} $$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dz}{\cosh(z\sqrt{2})}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}\tag{B}$$
hence
$$ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{\cosh(x)+\cosh(y)}=\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{dx\,dy}{2\cosh\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\cosh\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right)} =\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{du\,dv}{2\cosh(u\sqrt{2})\cosh(v\sqrt{2})}$$
simply equals $\color{red}{\large \pi^2}$.

Comment: Last line Second Integral: The second $\displaystyle\cosh$ must have the $\displaystyle\left(x \color{red}{\large -} y \over 2\right)$ argument. Isn't it ?. Otherwise, it's a clever answer.

Comment: @FelixMarin: correct, typo fixed.